# IE div won't shrink correspondingly when window is shrinked in size

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, html, extjs, resize

I have a div whose height is controlled by a javascript, which supposed will change the size of the div whenever the window is resized. It works fine now when enlarge the window, but doesn't work when shrink the window. what might be the reason? I have the code below

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function window_resize() {
            var height = 0;
            var body = window.document.body;
            if (window.innerHeight) {
                height = window.innerHeight;
            } else if (body.parentElement.clientHeight) {
                height = body.parentElement.clientHeight;
            } else if (body && body.clientHeight) {
                height = body.clientHeight;
            }

            var element = document.getElementById('test');
            element.style.height = height*80/100 + 'px';
        }

        Sys.Application.add_init(function (sender, args) {
            $addHandler(window, 'resize', window_resize);
            $addHandler(window, 'onload', window_resize);
            document.body.onresize = window_resize;
            document.body.onload = window_resize;
        });

    </script>

    <div id="test" style="width:1000px;padding:0px;margin:0px;">
        <spc:Explorer ID="explorer" runat="server"></spc:Explorer>
    </div>
```

Comment: Are you using a javascript library here?

Comment: Yes, there is a control (id of 'explorer') in the div. essentially, the control is from extjs.

Answer (score 0):

I'll guess that the div is too small when you make the window smaller. The likely reason is that reducing the window size makes scroll bars appear (even though they aren't shown) so the calculation of the window size is inside the scroll bars.

One solution is to apply `body.style.display = 'none'` to the body, get the size of the window, then do `body.style.display = ''`.